# What is the time-complexity of this for-loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, time, complexity-theory

```
for i in range(n - length + 1):
     minimumvalue = min(diskSpace[i:i + length])
     minimumList.insert(len(minimumList), minimumValue)

return(max(minimumArray)
```

So, for i in range takes O(n) time, python min function is O(n) time and insert is 0(n) time. Since these are inside my for loop would my total time complexity be O(n^2) or O(n)?

Comment: .... what are the inputs here? Is `length` variable? Does it depend on `n`?

Comment: As an aside, instead of `minimumList.insert(len(minimumList), minimumValue)` use `minimumList.append(minimumValue)`

Comment: "and insert is 0(n) time." it isn't, if you are inserting at the end, i.e `.append`ing... that is (amortized) constant time

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hi, this is a sliding window problem, the length is the segment length of the window, and n is the total length of the list. So n - length + 1 will give you total possible sliding windows. For example, diskSpace = [1,2,3] then n = 3, we can let length = 2. Then numbers of sliding window would be 2, eg [1,2] and [2,3]. I am just finding the minimum value with min and inserting to another array. Then I find the max of that minimum list. So max(1,2) would be 2 in our example. I think total complexity is O(n*length)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's O(n), because you're wrong about the complexities of the `min()` and `insert()` functions.

`min()` is generally O(n), but you're always calling it with the same `length` elements. Unless `length` is dependent on `n`, this can be treated as constant time.

`insert()` is also normally O(n), but you're inserting at the end by specifying the position `len(minimumList)`, so this is amortized constant time. In fact, inserting at that position is equivalent to `minimumList.append(minimumValue)`, which is amortized constant time.

The only part of the code that depends on `n` is the number of iterations of `for i in range(n - length + 1):`

If `length` is an input to the complexity, then the total complexity is O(n*length).

Answer (score 0):

The min function is O(n), because it is a constant amount of operations per element ( n * some constant). Your for loop does a this for each element (n * (some constant * n)).

So that would be n * n (We can leave out the constant, because that is not really important to see how well this function scales), thus your runtime is O(n^2).

Comment: but it isn't clear if `min` is being affected by `n`. it could be that `min(diskSpace[i:i + length])` is *constant* with respect to N if `length` doesn't depend on `n`. So consider, `for _ in range(n): min(range(100))` is *linear time* .